# Cannot Access responseJSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code and I want to access the json of the outside of the initial call.

```
var crimes = $.getJSON('url');

console.log(crimes);
```

the console logs an object with a "responseJSON" element, but I can't access it. The code:

```
console.log(crimes[responseJSON]);
```

returns an error saying respponseJSON is undefined.  I need to cycle through this large dataset in another for look so I only want to call it once rather than every time in the loop that comes after.  How do I access the responseJSON object?

Comment: Try crimes.responseJSON.  If that also gives an undefined error then most likely it is actually a string and not an object so you need to deserialize it to an object.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. Please read the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: That doesn't really help me understand how to access the JSON outside the initial $.getJSON() call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "outside the initial $.getJSON() call". What does "outside" mean here? How would "inside" look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON` returns a [`jqXHR`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object, and while it may have a `responseJSON` property, you cannot access it this way (or at that moment). You have to **"wait"** until the browser performed the Ajax request. You do this by passing a **callback** to `$.getJSON`, which gets called when the response is available.

From the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) (adapted):

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  // access data here
});
```

> The `success` callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the `$.parseJSON()` method.

It seems you are not familiar with Ajax, so you should definitely read the [jQuery tutorial about Ajax.](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

See also: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196)